# Javascript library for autocomplete like ide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-select2

I'm looking to create an autocomplete textbox in javascript which behaves like autocompete in a development IDE.

My data is infinitly recursive and each child could contain thousands of items.  Simple Json would look like this:

```
[{
    id: 123,
    name:abc,
    children:
        [
            {
                id: 156,
                name:xyz,
                children:
                    [
                     ....
                    ]
             },....
        ]
},...]
```

For each item i'd like to be able to search and autocomplete.  Ideally the data would be retrieved with a rest call each time the user completes passing the previously selected item's id.

e.g.  for the json above... When the user enters "a" they would get "abc" as an autocomplete option.  When they select "abc" and then type "x", "xyz" would be the next autocomplete option. So i'd end up with "abc.xyz" in the text box.  Obviously in the real world i'd enforce more than 1 character input.

Are there any libraries out there which already provide this behaviour so i don't have to re-invent the wheel?  The closest i've found is select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and i've tried to use the jquery autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) but can't quite get the behaviour i'm after.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does select2 not do that rules it out as an option? Just trying to get a full grasp

Comment: It might do what i'm after but i can't see how. Specifically, using a previously selected item to continue the autocomplete with another related search.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this: https://github.com/cootetom/jQuery-JSON-Suggest-Search-Box

Check it. I am not sure, it can handle nested elements.